# ¿Cómo hago un reporte usando un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, jasper-reports, ireport

Estoy intentando crear un reporte con un ArrayList pero obtengo la Excepción

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils
```

No se si estoy realizando algo mal a la hora de realizar el reporte o es que me falta algún .jar
Acá les dejo como intento crear el reporte, con iReport.

```
        JasperReport reporte = null;
        String rutaPDF = "C:\\RYL Jerusalén\\Source\\Reportes\\ReporteCotizarCompra.jasper";
        reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(rutaPDF);
        JasperPrint impresion = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(detalleCompra));
        JasperViewer PDF = new JasperViewer(impresion, false);
        PDF.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        PDF.setVisible(true);
```

El detalle de compra viene de acá:

```
            Object[] ob = new Object[vistaNuevaCompra.tablaDetalleCompra.getColumnCount()];
            ob[0] = i + 1;
            ob[1] = modeloTablaCompra.getValueAt(i, 1);
            ob[2] = modeloTablaCompra.getValueAt(i, 2);
            ob[3] = modeloTablaCompra.getValueAt(i, 5);
            ob[4] = (Float) modeloTablaCompra.getValueAt(i, 2) * (Integer) modeloTablaCompra.getValueAt(i, 5);
            DetalleCompra detalle = new DetalleCompra((String) ob[1], (int) ob[3], (float) ob[4], (float) ob[2]);
            cotice.add(detalle);
```

(Como podrán ver los datos provienen de un JTable)

Y finalmente esta es la estructura del detalle de compra:

```
public DetalleCompra(String producto, int cantidad, float subtotal, float precio) {
        this.producto = producto;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías indicar en qué parte del código se lanza la exepción?

Comment: Justo acá:
JasperPrint impresion = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(detalleCompra));

Comment: Puedes agregar más detalles de la excepción por favor?

Comment: Verificar si los tipos de datos en tu xml sean iguales a los tipos de datos que recoge tu jtable viendo en propiedades

Comment: La clase que te dice que falta esta en https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/download_beanutils.cgi te recomiendo agregarla al classpath y contarnos si es que no funciona